# Як розібрати за будовою слово "чаклувати"?

Tags: словотворення

Наприклад, є слово "чарувати". Якщо ж його розібрати за будовою, то буде: чар/ува/ти. Тут легко, бо бачимо, від якого слова утворено: чари.

Якщо ж проаналізувати слово **"чаклувати"** за аналогією до попереднього, теоретично вийде так: ***чакл/ува/ти***.

А от як визначити, від якого слова походить лексема "чаклувати"?
Якщо ж від чаклування, то можна і так: ***чаклув/а/ти***.

Як тоді правильно розібрати за будовою?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Норми української літературної мови
О. Синявський](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky)

чакл/ува/ти
чакл/ува/ння
чакл/ун/ство
чакл/івниця
чакл/ій
ча́кл/о

ЕСУМ 6, 227

> **чакло** (*колосове*) (бот.) «актея колосиста (чернесь), Actaea spicata L.» Нед, Mak; — не зовсім ясне; можливо, повʼязане з *чаклува́ти*, оскільки рослина викликає тяжке отруєння. — Нейштадт 252—253
>
> **чаклувати** чарувати», [*чакли́*] «чари», [*чаклівни́ця*] «чарівниця» Нед, [*чаклі́й*] «чаклун», *чаклування*, *чаклун*, *чаклунка*, *чаклунство*; — специфічно українське утворення не зовсім ясного походження; реконструювалася (Потебня РФВ 1 266) первісна форма **шакловати*, яка також не має достовірної етимології; можливо, основа цього слова тюркського походження, пор. тур. çakmak «забивати; викрешувати (вогонь); блискати; здогадуватися, кумекати».